# I am having some trouble with Android screen densities

Tags: android, screen

I'm currently in the beginning stages of developing an app for Android. 
I know there are 3 different screen densities: HDPI, MDPI, and LDPI. I know that the majority of phones use an 800x480 screen resolution or for older generation devices, a 480x320 screen resolution. What I need to know is which density category would these screen resolutions fall under? When I put images made for 800x480 in the MDPI folder, they turn out blurry when I'm running the app.

Can someone please walk me through how to correctly create images for these different screen resolutions and densities?

Answer (score 0):

Density is not only about screen size in pixels, it is also about screen size in inches. You can have 800x480 resolution but with screen of 10' you will not have HDPI.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that Olegas linked you has all the information you need to set up the layouts.

Basically, you want to create layouts for each screen size (in cm or inches). For that, you need to create different folders, and name them `res/layout-small`, `res/layout-normal`, `res/layout-large` and `res/layout/xlarge`.

You will want also to create Bitmaps with different sizes for each screen density (in dpi). Again, you need to create several alternative folders: `res/drawable-ldpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi` and `res/drawable-hdpi`.

the Android OS will decide which set of layouts and which set of drawables to use depending on the device specs. The range of densities are described in this section: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

To have an idea of the size of the bitmaps you will need, you can follow the icon design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to deal with this problem (and, as far as I can tell, the base Android source does the same thing) is to just generate a high definition image and put it in the HDPI folder, then let Android handle the downsampling for you. You only need to provide lower resolution images when the downsampled image would not have sufficient contrast, or just look wrong. I might be wrong, but I have yet to find a screen combo that doesn't look right, at least image wise. Layouts, well, that's something else.

Answer (score -1):

There is no official standard because density is about pixels per inch, not screen resolution. But any screen that has a 800x480 resolution most likely draws from the hdpi folder, thats why you're seeing it blurry. Find out what the target screen density is and use this equation:

px = dp * (screen_density / 160)

Where screen_density is the device's screen density.

Comment: My CLIQ is a 3.2" 320x480 screen. The Nexus One is 3.7" 480x320 screen. I have images that would fit my CLIQ in the MDPI folder, and images that would fit the Nexus One in the HDPI folder. Images show up fine on my CLIQ, but in my Gingerbread emulator, I think it draws from the mdpi folder, so the images are stretched out and blurry.

Comment: The nexus one is not 480x320. The nexus one is 800x480 and 240 density. I have one. And regarding your emulator it depends what API version you're running.